# Adding a target to Html.ActionLink

Tags: razor, html.actionlink

I'm trying to add a named target to an Html.ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search Agents", "Index", "DSSAgent", null, new { target = "SearchiFrame", @style="color: Red;" })
```

but when I inspect the HTML, the target is _blank. (it picked up the red color though)

I tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890138/t4mvc-html-actionlink-or-html-routelink-how-to-add-target), but it's a different variation of HTML.Action link and did not solve my issue.

Comment: Can you post the iframe tag?

Comment: There is no iFrame, I want it to open in a new tab/window, but a named one.  That way if they click on the link again, it just switches focus to the already open one.

Answer (score 2):

These are allowed attributes for target:

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

Browser will ignore any other words with underscore but the 4 above.

If you're not using frames, you could add ViewBag.Title to your new tab page like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchiFrame";   
}
```